# php+apache - determine if a file has been served/accessed?

Tags: debian

I have a process that is creating a file that needs to be accessible by a public link. The server is apache2 on debian 10. I want to know when/if that file has been served, and trigger a php process. It would be good if I could call a php page through the web and have it show me a "yes/no" status if the file had been accessed.

how would you go about setting up something like this? Would it be a php script executing in apache and somehow consuming and parsing the access log? Or is there a way to have a process watch a file/directory to see a read operation then trigger something else (e.g. touching a file elsewhere to show the read has occurred).

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you are asking here.

When the file is "served" you get an entry in your access_log. If you want additional actions when the file is "served", keep it outside the document root and provide the URL of a script which reads and returns the file. If you don't know the name of the file in advance, or don't know how to map the filename to a PHP script (mod_rewrite, pathinfo, index handler) then hang the script off the 404 handler.

If you need a mechanism which works for access to the file other than via the webserver, then put it on a filesystem mounted with "atime" then compare the mtime and atime or monitor with inotify.